Script to find top traders for a specific token?
How to build functionality like DexScreener top traders API? My goal is to return top traders for a certain token with their PnL and un-realized PnL.

Scrape Photon using a headless browser and access their API using your cookies.

This answer is a little vague - can you add an example of the actual request to help others?

answer is clear.

reader should be able to figure it out

The reason I'm asking is that another user flagged this for moderation as lacking details. I think it's a good answer - by adding something like "send a GET request to example.com/api/foo with the following query {} and these headers" (or just pasting in some code with the cookie redacted) I can give you karma for a god question and answer and  keep the other person happy (plus help the next person that wants to get the top traders). Can you please paste your HTTP request with the cookie redacted?
